# UDP client-server question

Tags: c#, client, udp

I'm trying to write a client-server console application on C# using UDP.
And i have one question.
So, when i send command from client to server - servers must have a read IP adress.
client must get some settings from server,but in this case client must have real IP adress too. Other application like games do not require client real IP. What must do I to it work in such a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Games either use the host computer with a public IP as a server or the server itself as a server.

A client with private IP establishes a connection with a server and the server then uses the connection to return data to a client (similar to browsers).

In C# you could use the [NetworkStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx) class for TCP and [UdpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx) for UDP.

Comment: UDP is a datagram protocol, NetworkStream is stream-based - i.e. TCP.  I believe NetworkStream will NOT work with UDP

Comment: Oops, you are absolutely correct of course - missed the UDP part. `UdpClient` it is then!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly: you could use `Socket.ReceiveFrom`, which will tell the server the IP address of the client who is sending a request.

Answer (score 0):

Using Socket.BeginReceiveFrom / EndReceiveFrom the server gets the IP address of the client. If the server needs to reply, it uses the IPEndPoint.